# about matlab's Adaptfilt.<algorithm> function

Tags: matlab

Matlab's DSP toolbox has a function called adaptfilt., where calling adaptfilt is not enough, but you must add the **.< algorithm>** where the algorithm can be one of the many things, which we can view using help adaptfilt. What kind of Matlab structure has been used here (or what is the . operator and how can I make my own function that has to be called using a dot).

Also, the result of doing, say, adaptfilt.fdaf, gives a result that seems like a structure. How can I view all the elements of this structure (that is, if there are any more members besides the values that are returned on the screen by the function itself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adaptfilt` is a class definition, of which `fdaf` is a member. Then, you use the dot operator to access the static member of the class. See [Static Methods](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html) in the MATLAB documentation. In summary, to define a similar function yourself use

```
classdef MyClass
   ...
   methods(Static)
      function y = yourFunc(x)
          ...
      end
    end
end
```

The result you're getting from `adaptfilt.fdaf` is in fact an object. The [`adaptfilt.fdaf`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/dsp/ref/adaptfilt.fdaf.html) documentation page outlines the members of the object.